# Config nested location NGINX

Tags: django, nginx

Now I config my location in Nginx:

```
server {
    location / {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I want to change it into nested location:

`http://exp.com/api` instead of  the current: `http://exp.com/`

I tried but it's not success:

```
server {
    location / {
      location /api {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`location` does not need to be nested.

Have you tried the following?

```
server {
    location /api {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```